# Why is there no argc when passing arguments to an executable in C#?

Tags: c#, c, command-line, command-line-arguments

For example if we pass command line arguments to a C executable, it will pass argument count (`argc`) and argument array (`argv[]`). But in C# if we pass arguments to executable it will only pass the arguments array (`args[]`) and not argument count (`argc`).

Is information sent same way to `Main()` functions and then parsed by programming language? Or is the operating system doing all of this?

Answer (score 6):

Arrays in C# are objects which include information about their length. Arrays in C are just chunks of contiguous memory. When an array is passed to a function in C, a pointer to its first element is passed. This pointer does not contain any information about the length of that array, so that information has to be passed as a separate argument.

One place where we might not pass this length argument is when passing strings in the form of char arrays. We are assuming in these cases that the char array is terminated by a null character (`'\0'`) and we can use this sentinel to find the end of the string. Passing a char array that is not null-terminated to such a function can lead to out of bounds access and undefined behavior.

Comment: So parameters are sent same way for both languages but programming language decides how to interpret(and parse) it right?

Comment: @Aka the shell doesn't know what language you used to create the program. It is job of the startup code to provide parameters to your program in a suitable way.

Comment: What do you mean by startup code can you explain?

Comment: @Gerhardh when I send arguments to executable in C or C# what parses my arguments? Parameters for C executable are parsed different than C#, what ensures this behavior of parsing parameters? I use shell to pass arguments right but then what parses(or translates) my arguments to certain parameters(or just one parameter in case of C#)

Comment: @Aka Your `main` function is not started out of thin air. Your compiler is to provide some code that does everything required to prepare the environment for your `main` function. That includes setting up the stack, initializing variables and preparing the parameters passed to `main`. This is the startup code of your program. The C standard defines what is passed via `argc` and `argv'. In C# other rules apply and I don't know whether that is done in .Net environment or in some startup code of your C# .exe file.